# Backslash in the end of comment lines in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, ide, editor, highlighting

Does your editor/ide highlight that `a++;` in this C/C++ code as part of a comment?

```
int a=1;
//some comment \
a++;
printf("%d\n",a);
```

And what about this?

```
int a=1;
//some comment ??/
a++;
printf("%d\n",a);
```

Comment: BTW, should it be a comment? I'm confused.

Comment: I think this should be community wiki.

Comment: I once asked "what's wrong" sort of question as a "c++ quiz" using this weirdness on stackoverflow (of course, replacing "\" by the trigraph "// what the heck ??/"). And the question was downvoted heavily. People didn't like how they were fooled :)

Comment: @Javier:yes -- line splicing happens in phase 2 of translation, replacement of a comment by a space happens in phase 3.

Comment: The lesson, Don't have a backslash in C99 one-lined comments, please. :)

Comment: The trigraph question is tricky, personally I compile with trigraphs disabled so I am perfectly fine with my IDE not recognizing them.

Comment: I'm confused, can someone explain? are those a++; supposed to be part of the comment?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking whether a particular feature is implemented in an arbitrary IDE. This is a "list-style" question that isn't useful to readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

emacs 22.3.1: No to both, sadly

Comment: The same for my Emacs 23.1.1
Should we file a bug report?

Comment: <flamebait>That's why you have to switch to vim</flamebait>

Answer (score 2):

VC6, Visual Studio 2003, 2005, 2008, 2010 all do.

Answer (score 2):

Slickedit - yes

KDevelop - yes

QT Creator - No

CodeBlocks - No

Answer (score 2):

vim 7.2 sees it as a comment, and gcc 3.4.3 compiles it as a comment.

Comment: The install of vim I have (7.2, Ubuntu 10.04) sees the first one correctly, but misses on the trigraph.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, TextMate does it.

Answer (score 1):

Kate (3.4) only highlights the first test, fails hilighting the second test

```
// hello folks \
int a = 0;

// hello folks ??/
int a = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://forums.topcoder.com/?module=Thread&threadID=666932

> Quick note on which popular editors
>   show this as a comment : vim - yes
>   emacs - no :) kate - no gedit - yes
>   netbeans - yes kwrite - yes

Answer (score 0):

XCode and CodeWarrior handle it properly. (But not the trigraph, lol.)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode sees the first as a comment, the second not.

Answer (score 0):

Good question! I was going to ask a question about this until I found this one.

The Visual-DSP++ IDE from Analog Devices does not highlight either comment when writing in assembly or C. For example:

```
r1 = dm(pPointer1);      // Store pointer to r0\
r0 = lshift r1 by -16;   // Not highlighted as a comment but DOES NOT EXECUTE.
dm(i0,m1) = r0;
dm(i0,m1) = r1;
```